# Add more than one evaluator in NEO4J

Tags: java, neo4j

How can i add more than one evaluator?
For Example -

```
TraversalDescription TRAVERSAL = Traversal.description()
.breadthFirst()
.evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition());
```

I also want to add

```
Evaluators.toDepth(2)
```

How can i do it?

In other words i want to create a list of evaluators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the evaluator with another call to the evaluator() method like:

```
TraversalDescription TRAVERSAL = Traversal.description()
.breadthFirst()
.evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition())
.evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(2));
```